# Non-deterministic errors when using nested sshfs

Tags: osx, git, android

The OSX implementation of `sshfs` [doesn't like to connect to my Android phone running SSHDroid](https://github.com/osxfuse/sshfs/issues/8), so I'm attempting to gain access by mounting an ubuntu VM via `sshfs` which in turn has a mountpoint to the phone.

My main goal is to pull `git` commits from repos on the phone to those on my MacBook and vice versa.  My typical workflow is 1) commit changes on the Mac and on the phone; 2) pull new commit from the phone; 3) merge on the Mac; 4) pull merge commit back to the phone.

This mostly works, but I'm seeing `git fetch` (fetching to the repo located on the phone) frequently fail with

```
error: unable to create temporary file: Interrupted system call
fatal: failed to write object
fatal: unpack-objects failed
```

This doesn't happen consistently — sometimes `git fetch` completes successfully and all is well.  Perhaps it might be some sort of timing issue.

Is there an option I can pass to one or both of the `sshfs` invocations to make this work smoothly?

I realize that I could just pull via an intermediate repo on the VM, but that would be kind of a hassle.

Comment: I don't know why you're getting those errors, but are you able to have `git` installed on the phone? Then you could fetch using the Git protocol over SSH without the need to use sshfs at all.

Comment: That's a good question.  I don't know whether or not I'm able to have `git` installed on the (unrooted) phone.  I've installed [SGit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.sheimi.sgit), but it doesn't seem to be able to import a repo that's located on the external SDCard, so is kind of useless to me.  If there's some way to access `git` from the command line, that would be kind of appealing.  But there are so many other applications for being able to access the phone's filesystem directly from a PC that it is probably a waste of time to mess around with running `git` on the phone.

Answer (score 3):

Use `git fetch --quiet`. In order to implement progress meter `git` uses `setitimer()` which in turn causes frequent `SIGALRM`s to be delivered. `sshfs` doesn't handle them very well, causing either `Interrupted system call` or `File exists` errors depending on the timing and command. The problem is timing-dependent and gets worse with larger repositories.